# change the behavior to appear on timeline

Tags: facebook-apps, html-email

how to change this behaviour that appears on newsfeeds

`[FacebookUser] likes a link on [AppName]`

to read this way:

`[FacebookUser] likes an offer on [AppName]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create an `offer` object on the Open Graph for the [built-in `like` action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/submission-process/opengraph/guidelines/#builtin). Read about defining custom objects [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-object/).

Comment: Please mark as accepted if this answered your question so that others may find answers more easily.